# Images doesn't loaded

Tags: codeigniter

My code:

```
<?php
    foreach ($berita as $data) {
?>
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/home/berita/'.$data->id); ?>"><img  src="<?php echo base_url ('upload/berita/'.$data->gambar); ?>" title="<?php echo $data->judul ;?>"></a>
<div class="slide-caption n hidden-phone">
<h3><?php echo $data->judul ;?></h3>
<?php
}
?>
```

when in localhost it works but when I hosting it it won't work
is it cause image size too big?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

After modifying php.ini file(s), you need to restart your server to use new configuration.

If you can't access to php.ini file you can handle it using .htaccess as below :

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
   php_value post_max_size 40M
</IfModule>
```